# Command for inequality of char

Tags: java

I want to ask the user about whether he wants to continue playing or not. For this I have used,

```
char choice; 
do
{
     System.out.println("Would you like to continue?(y/n)");
     choice=sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
     if (choice!='y' && choice!='n')  
     {  
           System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
     }
}while (choice!='y' && choice!='n');
```

This is working fine and I didn't face any issues, but is that the right way?

Comment: Try with an empty input, you'll have *java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some minor issues with this:

- The condition to check the value of choice is duplicated
- The program will crash if the input is empty
- The variable choice is declared outside the loop body
- The formatting is a bit unusual

I suggest this way instead:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Would you like to continue?(y/n)");
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    if (!line.isEmpty()) {
        char choice = line.charAt(0);
        if (choice == 'y' || choice == 'n') {  
            return choice;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
}
```

Comment: While we're at it - we wouldn't want to punish a user typing 'Y' or 'N' uppercase, would we?

Comment: Well this is working absolutely fine when it is about handling empty inputs, but when I am entering something like "yhfkshs" or "n fds", it recognises them as "y" and "n" respectively; and I don't think this should happen. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @ShinjineeMaiti yes, just like your original. I did not change the behavior. Feel free to change the behavior, but that has nothing to do with this code review.

Comment: @janos I think I got how to solve this one....thanks for your help.